# Apache Ignite Force Server Mode

Tags: ignite

We are trying to prevent our application startups from just spinning if we cannot reach the remote cluster. From what I've read [Force Server Mode](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/clients-vs-servers) states

> In this case, discovery will happen as if all the nodes in topology
>   were server nodes.

What i want to know is:

1. Does this client then permanently act as a server which would run computes and store caching data?
2. If connection to the cluster does not happen at first, a later connection to an establish cluster cause issue with consistency? What would be the expect behavior with a Topology version mismatch? Id their potential for a split brain scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. No, it's still a client node, but behaves as a server on discovery protocol level. For example, it can start without any server nodes running.
2. Client node can never cause data inconsistency as it never stores the data. This does not depend `forceServerMode` flag.

Comment: Adding on to this. In testing, if we bring a up the client node first with forceServerMode then bring up the server it never connects to the cluster and we get a org.apache.ignite.cache.CacheServerNotFoundException: Failed to map keys for cache (all partition nodes left the grid). When trying to hit it.